# Positioning embed over embed with wmode direct

Tags: html, css, flash

I need to position a flash banner over gpu accelerated video player. I have read somewhere, that `wmode direct` is very important. But don't remember why.

How do i position a banner over it if i can't set `wmode to opaque`?

Thanks.

Comment: Yep gpu acceleration is throwing an exception if direct is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : You can't.

Long answer : wmode direct remove the swf from the browser display, and placed on top of it. That way, it is possible to make use of the gpu. With wmode opaque (or transparent), the swf is displayed by the browser, and the gpu acceleration can't be used.
The drawback of using wmode direct is that the swf is displayed on over all the document. So nothing can be placed over it (except maybe another direct swf - no tested, and I wouldn't recommend it). Ever.

What are the workarounds possible from this problems ? I can think of two :

- foregoing gpu acceleration. Does your swf really needs gpu acceleration ? Chances are, if you don't display video, 3D graphics, or hundreds of moving sprites, that it doesn't really need it. If so, use wmode opaque, you'll loose a bit of performance, but you'll be able to place your banner.
- place de banner **within** the swf. This'll need to edit the flash, but you could display a banner from within it. As long that this banner is an image, or another swf, it wouldn't be very hard using the `Loader` class.

Comment: Yea i implemented it via "within swf" solution. It's only, working solution. Thanks though. :)